# Can I change the equipment of my party members other than Rush?

Tags: pc, the-last-remnant

In The Last Remnant normally it is not possible to change the equipment of a leader besides Rush. However after looking on the Internet I saw that if you changed the line bExSettingUseAllMemberEquip=FALSE from FALSE to TRUE it would allow you to control the equipment of your other leaders. However, when I attempted to start the game after making only this change ,I got a popup that the launcher was broken. I went back and changed to back to FALSE and it again worked. Was this change ever valid or has a update been made to stop it from being used. Or am I just doing this wrong? I play the game off of steam.

Comment: Could you describe your process in more detail? I made the same edits I assume you made (editing `bExSettingUseAllMemberEquip` from `FALSE` to `TRUE`, also tried `true`, in `RushEngine.ini`) and I was able to start the game successfully using Steam in both cases.

Comment: I think my mistake may be the file I'm using. I have gone through all the folders the but only one I can find with this command line is in BaseEngine. I got to this through Program Files(x86)>Steam>Steamapps>common>The Last Remnant>Engine>Config. I can't find a RushEngine.ini file anywhere so I assumed it was the same file just with a different name from buying the disc vs. buying from steam.

Comment: The `RushEngine.ini` file should exist regardless as far as I know. Can you try and make the same edit in `My Documents/My Games/The last remnant/RushGame/Config/RushEngine.ini` (if it is there) and see if it works?

Comment: Nope it isn't there. All the items in that folder are labeled Default____ whatever the file is.

Comment: The `DefaultEngine.ini` file is supposed to be located in `steamapps/common/the last remnant/RushGame/Config`, (Note the `steamapps/common` part), while the `RushEngine.ini` is located in `My Documents/My Games/The last remnant/RushGame/Config`. Please check the path and make sure you are looking at the correct folder. If for some reason it just isn't there I would suggest verifying the integrity of the game files and/or reinstalling the game.

Comment: Its there! didn't know there were files in 2 different places! You should make this an official answer so I can accept :)

Comment: I will do that. Happy I could help! =)

Comment: This question and @Merigrim's answer made me play the game again. What a difference such a seemingly small thing can make! I've edited the title to make it relevant to more people and more discoverable, hope that's cool with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said in the comments, the file you had modified was `steamapps/common/the last remnant/Engine/Config/BaseEngine.ini`, which caused your error.

When modifying INI settings, such as `bExSettingUseAllMemberEquip`, you want to edit the `RushEngine.ini` file located in `My Documents/My Games/The last remnant/RushGame/Config`. The `My Documents` folder may be named differently on your computer though.

If you can't find the `RushEngine.ini` file, make sure that you are looking in the correct folder. It's easy to mistake the path for `steamapps/common/the last remnant/RushGame/Config` (note the `steamapps/common` part), where you will only find files such as `DefaultEngine.ini`.